# Custom AWS-X-ray instrumentation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I have a simple Spring boot rest API which when get called trigger calls to three different API using rest template, collect data and perform business operation mostly private and service layer methods those I don't need to trace in X-ray.

I have implemented the required configuration and uses `@XRayEnabled` on the class which I need to trace, but I am seeing x-ray tracing all the methods calls in the overall flow.

Wherever In flow I need tracing I have open and close a new subsegment like this

```
AWSXRay.beginSubsegment("Name");
AWSXRay.endSubsegment();
```

How can I make this not to trace private and other methods.

Answer (score 0):

AWS xray java sdk annotation `XRayEnabled` is used on class.
A workaround is moving private methonds which you don't want to be instrumented to an util class.